# $L_{s} [t f(t) f'(t)] $

Tags: laplace-transform

Is there any simplification by the way of standard properties of Laplace Transform for this? $$L_{s} [t f(t) f'(t)]$$

where $f'(t)$ is $\frac{d}{dt} f(t)$

Alternately, is there a simplification of $L_{s} [f(t) f'(t)]$, so that I can compute my original expression by computing the derivative $-\frac{d}{ds} L_{s} [f(t) f'(t)]$ ?

Comment: I think it should be like this $L_{s}[f(t)f'(t)]=\frac{f^{2}(0)}{2}+sL_{s}[\frac{f^{2}(t)}{2}]$.

Comment: There is a minus sign in front of $f^2(0)$ @kolobokish if I am not wrong.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. @Isham. You are not wrong.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^{+\infty} f'(t)f(t) e^{-st} \, \mathrm d t = I(s)$$

Define:

$$u(t)=f(t)e^{-st}$$
$$u'(t)=f'(t)e^{-st}-s e^{-st} f(t)$$
$$v'(t)=f'(t)$$
$$v(t)=f(t)$$

Integrate by parts: $\int v'u=vu-\int vu'$:

$$I(s)=f^2(t)e^{-st}\vert_{t=0}^{t \to + \infty} - I(s) + s \int_0^{+\infty} f^2(t)e^{-st} \, \mathrm d t$$

Solve for $I(s)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since:
$$\mathcal {L}\{tg(t)\}=-\frac {d}{ds}\mathcal {L}\{g(t)\}$$
We have:
$$\mathcal {L}[tf(t)f′(t)]=-\frac {d}{ds}\mathcal {L}\{f(t)f′(t)\}$$
$$\mathcal {L}[tf(t)f′(t)]=-\frac 1 2\frac {d}{ds}\mathcal {L}\{(f^2(t))′\}$$
Use the fact that : 
$$ \mathcal{L}{(g'(t))}=sG(s)-g(0) $$
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal {L}[tf(t)f′(t)]&=-\frac 1 2\frac {d}{ds}(s\mathcal {L}\{f^2(t)\}(s)-f^2(0)) \\
\mathcal {L}[tf(t)f′(t)]&=-\frac 1 2\frac {d}{ds}(s\mathcal {L}\{f^2(t)\}(s)) \\
\end{align}
$$